# How do i detect Ears in photo using OpenCv ,inside android app?

Tags: android, opencv

How do i detect Ears in photo using OpenCv ,inside android app Thanks in 
Adavance. I Know about Google Invision, but i found some issue ear recognisation in the vision api.Please suggest possible solution ?

Comment: what problem did you face in google invision?

Comment: @Redman https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/70

Comment: i just checked and yes you were right the ears are not getting detected in google invision . Even my project is based on google invision ,i guess even i have to shift to opencv library, I will update here if i found some thing useful about opencv